# How do I use Finder on macOS to copy original photos from iPhone?

Tags: macos, iphone, icloud, finder, photos

Two years of full-resolution photos are missing from my Photos library on macOS (Ventura)—owing to my not having selected [Copy items to Photos Library](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/464403/21435). After running `ls -lR` on both the old and the new Macs, it's clear the original files are on neither. I *can*, however, see the original files on the iPhone.

Connecting the iPhone by USB cable to Ventura and using Photos on macOS to import the original files (click on the iPhone device under "Devices"; select all photos; create new folder; and then click "import selected") does absolutely nothing.

Though I am reluctant to use iCloud as I have no control whether (as I believe Google does) iCloud will lower the quality of the jpeg photos to save space, I am yielding and enabling upload of photos to iCloud (iPhone settings; Photos; iCloud Photos).

When I do so, I am pleasantly surprised to see the warning

> Photos Synced from Finder will be Removed.
> Syncing photos via Finder is not supported when iCould Photos is turned on.

[image: Photos Synced from Finder will be Removed.]

This suggests that I could in fact use just Finder to copy the original photos.

How do I use Finder to copy original photos? The iPhone does not appear in Finder when it's connected via USB.

Answer (score 0):

##### Method 1: from the iPhone (tedious)

Open the Photos app on the iPhone. Click "Select". Select a range (the UI appears to be: select the first photo; select the second image then drag).

Now click "Share" (up-arrow) and send via AirDrop the photos to the Mac.

Reading [here](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/102375) and
[there](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201302) I see that there is a better way, but it seems exclusive to using the system photo library. Those  short on space on the system disk and who are storing their Photo collection on an external disk are out of luck.

##### Method 2: from the Mac

Launch `Image Capture` on your Mac. Connect the iPhone and you will see a full list of the photos on your iPhone.

Yet one more method is through Finder on Mac. I used to see the iPhone on Finder, but now I can't (when connected through USB). It's unclear how to make the iPhone visible in Finder, or whether this will help with a "raw image  capture import".